# How to manage nuget packages without opening solution

Tags: nuget, xamarin.forms

I am unable to load my solution ever since I upgraded my nugget packages to the latest Xamarin.Forms alpha.

Can someone provide me an example of how I can point all nuget packages of a certain id to an earlier version without having my solution open?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to open the `packages.config` file in a text editor and remove the Xamarin.Forms values from it.

After that you can open your `.csproj` file (with a text editor) and also remove the references from it.

Now you should be able to open the project (with the visual studio) and add the references you want again via the nuget manager.